# Having trouble sending information to the server

Tags: javascript, react-native

My information is read from sqlite and a created json for each piece of information and these json are sent to the server.

the problem is that with more Json, it doesn't work 
and on the server side, it encounters an error json is sent at a time and they get the same id on the server.

When I send one by one, I don't have such a problem, but I find this problem when the number of two goes up

My Code:

```
db.transaction((tx) => {
        tx.executeSql(
          "SELECT * FROM VoucherTable INNER JOIN VoucherItemsTable ON VoucherItemsTable.VoucherId = VoucherTable.VoucherId",
          [],
          (tx, res) => {
            let rows = res.rows.length;
            if (rows > 0) {
              let VoucherTable = [];
              for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
                VoucherTable.push(res.rows.item(i));
              }
              this.setState({ VoucherTable: VoucherTable, VoucherTableLength: VoucherTable.length });

              let localVoucherId = -1;
              let voucherItemsData = "";
              let voucherData = "";
              let voucherItemCount = 0;

              VoucherTable.forEach((key, index) => {
                if (localVoucherId !== key.VoucherId && voucherData !== "") {
                  this.sendData(voucherData, voucherItemsData);
                  //reset variables     
                  voucherData = "";
                  voucherItemsData = "";
                  voucherItemCount = 0;
                }
                localVoucherId = key.VoucherId;
                if (voucherItemCount === 0) {
                  if (voucherData === "")
                    voucherData = '"VoucherId":' + key.VoucherId + ',"CreationTime":"' + Moment(key.CreationTime, 'jYYYY-jM-jD').format('YYYY-MM-DD') + '","Description":"' + key.Description + '"';

                  if (voucherItemsData !== "")
                    voucherItemsData += ",";
                  voucherItemsData += '{"Credit":' + key.Credit + ',"ItemDlRef":"' + key.ItemDlRef + '","ItemAccountSlRef":"' + key.ItemAccountSlRef + '","Description":"' + key.Description + '","CurrencyRef":' + key.CurrencyRef + ',"CurrencyRate":' + key.CurrencyRate + ',"CurrencyDebit":"' + key.CurrencyDebit + '","CurrencyCredit":"' + key.CurrencyCredit + '"}';
                  voucherItemCount++;
                } else {
                  voucherItemsData += ",";
                  voucherItemsData += '{"Debit":' + key.Debit + ',"ItemDlRef":"' + key.ItemDlRef + '","ItemAccountSlRef":"' + key.ItemAccountSlRef + '","Description":"' + key.Description + '","CurrencyRef":' + key.CurrencyRef + ',"CurrencyRate":' + key.CurrencyRate + ',"CurrencyDebit":"' + key.CurrencyDebit + '","CurrencyCredit":"' + key.CurrencyCredit + '"}';
                }
              })
              this.sendData(voucherData, voucherItemsData);
            } else {
              this.setState({ loading: false });
              this.autoClose('No data for sync!', 'Error', 3000);
            }
          },
          (err) => { console.log(err) }
        )
      });

sendData = (voucherData, voucherItemData) => {
      const data = '{' + voucherData + ',"Items":[' + voucherItemData + ']}';
      let VoucherJson = JSON.parse(data);

      //fetch
      let sycnAddress = this.state.syncAddress;
      var myHeaders = new Headers();
      myHeaders.append("token", this.state.Token);
      myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
      let Data = data;
      var requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: myHeaders,
        body: Data,
        redirect: 'follow'
      };
      fetch(sycnAddress + "SetVoucher", requestOptions)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
          if (responseJson.status === 1) {
            this.setState({ loading: false });
            this.autoClose('Sync Successfuly.', 'success', 3000);
          }
        return responseJson;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log('error' + error);
        });
    }
```

How to create a delay in sending data and send it to the server one by one ??

Answer (score 0):

API calls are async call. You can use either [promise](https://javascript.info/promise-basics) or [Async await](https://javascript.info/async-await).

promise

```js
fetch('/article/promise-chaining/user.json')
  .then(user => fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${user.name}`))
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(githubUser => new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    let img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = githubUser.avatar_url;
    img.className = "promise-avatar-example";
    document.body.append(img);

    setTimeout(() => {
      img.remove();
      resolve(githubUser);
    }, 3000);
  }))
  // triggers after 3 seconds
  .then(githubUser => alert(`Finished showing ${githubUser.name}`));
```

async await

```js
function async doSomeCrazyThingWithAPI(){
  let user = await fetch('/article/promise-chaining/user.json');
  let response = await fetch('https://api.github.com/users/${user.name}');
  let githubUser = await appendImageAndThenRemove(10);
  // Will wait for 10 seconds here
  alert(githubUser);
}
```

Comment: The code is in question or send me your email, I will send it to you

Comment: rajanshah.1910@gmail.com